# Transmitting the Correct Session Data when Multiple Tabs are Opened on a Web Browser

Tags: php

I have a PHP script (**script A**) that makes a query to the database, stores the result in a session variable and produces a HTML page containing a form that allows the user to post a submission (*optionally*). Upon submission, the result stored in the session variable is used for processing in another script (**script B**).

As the HTML page is not unique, the user may open multiple tabs showing different pages generated by **script A**. Since the session variable can only hold data for the latest generated page, when the user clicks on any of the previous tabs and do a submission, the wrong set of session data will be used.

One way to preventing this from happening is to force the page to automatically reload before submission occurs. Is there any better and **secure** way to do this short of re-querying the database in **script B**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a secret token and a hash of it.

Add the secret token to your `$_SESSION`.

Add the hash to the form as a hidden input element.

On Submission, create the hash from the secret token in `$_SESSION`.

Compare it to the submitted hash. If it mismatches, you know that the form is wrong for your session.

You can extend that, by keying the data with the hash inside your `$_SESSION`:

```
$_SESSION[$hash] = your form data
```

Then you can even process multiple forms (and multiple form instances) correctly.

Comment: ah, I see.. creating a unique element in session.. But the data consist of multiple variables. Can I store all of them into this hash element as an array within an array??

Answer (score 0):

> a PHP script (script A) that makes a query to the database, stores the result in a session variable

What for? What's the point in storing data you already have?

> Upon submission, the result stored in the session variable is used for processing in another script (script B)

What for? Why can't you submit your form directly to B?

I see no point in using sessions here at all. Or at least according to your current description.

Comment: Because the submission is optional, not compulsory.

Comment: So what? Every form in the world is optional. Like one to answer your question. Still there is no point in storing this form anywhere.

Comment: err.. why you get so heated up? Let me think through your question before answering, ok?

Comment: I tried but did not succeed to combine the two scripts. Script A accepts a `$_GET` variable too. The POST form is just a very small part of the whole HTML page and was added in much later because I don't want to have a separate page to receive just one variable. I will have look at it again tomorrow. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I managed to combine the two scripts, but that doesn't avoid re-querying the database upon submission. I don't see how it can be done without using `SESSION` since the `INSERT` statement relies on some output from the `SELECT` statement. It isn't as simple as it seems.